# Why the height of an element expressed in percentage does not work?

Tags: css

I was trying to create a responsive square and added the following:

```
.square {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

however, it expands horizontally but vertically does not expand at all...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
  <style>
    body{
      background: #cccede;
      
    }
    

    .square {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
       border: 2px solid black
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="square"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this snippet, why does the box not take the height of the windows to calculate its height?

Comment: Add `html,body{height:100%}`

Comment: it's work perfectly your square hight fit 50% of his parent,which is body and size of the body on page build is zero (and body is part of html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, `%` works from the container of the element, so you need to manually set a height / width for `body`.

However, you could also use [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units) / [`vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units), which are units for a percent of the viewport height, and viewport width respectively

```css
body {
  background: #cccede;
}

.square {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="square"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`height: 50%` means that it will be half as tall as its parent container. Your square is that small because it's inside the `body` tag which is small. You can make the `body` as tall as the screen by doing this:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```